# Sort Function Stopped Working - Google Apps Script & Sheets

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I have myself a bit of a head scratcher here. I have been using the below code for the past half year to detect an edit in a Google Sheet, stamp a date, and then sort my table by date from oldest to newest:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  bidTime(e)
}

function bidTime(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); //gets the active sheet being edited
  var sheetName = 'Active Bids'; //name of the sheet the script should work on
  var editCell = sheet.getActiveCell(); //gets the active cell being edited
  var colToWatch = 3 // watches for edits made in col C
  var colToStamp = 4 //timestamp in col D
  if (e.range.columnStart !== colToWatch || e.source.getActiveSheet()
    .getName() !== sheetName || e.value == '') return; {
  var writeVal = e.value !== '0' ? new Date() : "No bid.";
  e.source.getActiveSheet()
      .getRange(e.range.rowStart, colToStamp)
      .setValue(writeVal);
    }
  function bidSort() {
    var colSort = 5;
    var tableRange = "A2:Z150";
    if (editCell.getColumn() == colToWatch){
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( {column: colSort, ascending: true} );
    }
  }
  //function bidAmount() {
  //  var value = editCell.getValue();
  //  if (editCell.getColumn() == colToWatch AND value <= 0) return; {
  //}
  bidSort();
}
```

It had been working flawlessly up until this afternoon, I was tinkering around with the bidAmount function and I don't know if it did something to my code (I can't see how?) but now my sheet no longer sorts after applying the date stamp to column 4.

I have already tried to break the bidSort function out into it's own function and incorporating both functions into the onEdit function and neither appear to do anything. I have also tried defining the variables again within the bidSort function (which wasn't necessary prior to this afternoon) and still no dice.

I did make some largely cosmetic changes to the spreadsheet being referenced and added another sheet to the spreadsheet but I don't see why any of those things would effect my code.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on? The code literally hasn't changed in months and just started giving me issues today.

Let me know if you require any further information!

Comment: can you try applying your sort script to a new spreadsheet project and see if it still doesnt work?

Comment: Check your colSort number. When I changed it to 4, it sorted no problem.

Comment: Thanks guys (or girls)! I figured it out. I had added merged a number of cells together below the table to keep track of To-Dos in the sheet.

The issue was that my range was from A2:Z150, but I was only using A2:Z50. I changed my range to that and it sorted without issue.